# Signing message problem with GPG loopback pin-entry option

Tags: gnupg, gpg-agent

I am trying to encrypt and sign a file with gpg and loopback pinentry option, with the below command:

```
gpg --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase ="mypws" \
--ignore-time-conflict --ignore-valid-from \
--cipher-algo AES256 --symmetric --ignore-time-conflict \
--passphrase-file ~/.gnupg/PG/p-enckey --trust-model always -q --batch --yes --local-user "UserID" \
--sign --force-mdc \
--output /var/psigner/2 \
/var/psigner/1
```

however i got the below error message:

```
gpg: signing failed: Too much data for IPC layer
gpg: /var/psigner/1: sign+symmetric failed: Too much data for IPC layer
```

but with the below command, which a dialoge pops up to ask for the key passpharse, everything works fine.

```
gpg \
--ignore-time-conflict --ignore-valid-from \
--cipher-algo AES256 --symmetric --ignore-time-conflict \
--passphrase-file ~/.gnupg/PG/patch-enckey --trust-model always -q --batch --yes --local-user "UserID" \
--sign --force-mdc \
--output /var/psigner/2 \
/var/psigner/1
```

can anyone give me a advice to solve the problem?